# react-big-calendar - showing tooltip message when hover on no events dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

How we can show a tooltip/anyMessage("No booking this date") when mouse hover on no event date block ?

[image]

```
<Calendar
startAccessor={(event) => new Date(event.start)}
endAccessor={(event) => new Date(event.end)}
selectable
localizer={localizer}
views={["month", "week", "day"]}
loading={true}
-------
```

Comment: Did you get an answer for this ?